# Deleting elements with certain character in a list

Tags: python

```py
list = [['4H', '5D', '7C', 'AC'], ['AC', 'AS', 'AS']]
for i in list:
    for j in i:
        if j[0] == 'A':
            i.remove(j)
print(list)
```

I am essentially trying to remove all the elements in both lists that has 'A' as the first index of each element.
When I try to use the code above I seemed to get `[['4H', '5D', '7C'], ['AS']]`
How can I get `[['4H', '5D', '7C'], []]` instead?

Comment: you are deleting while itearting, that is the problem

Comment: I do not understand what it is that you are trying to do. Could you be a bit more specific? You code suggests you want to do delete all elements that start with `'A'` but your question title implies otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_list = [['4H', '5D', '7C', 'AC'], ['AC', 'AS', 'AS']]
for i in my_list:
    for j in i[::1]:
        if 'A' in j[0]:
            i.remove(j)
print(my_list)
```

use in better

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you modify a list while iterating on it. Imagine 2nd sublist being `['AS1', 'AS2', 'AS3']`

```
i = 0 => AS1 => deletes, that moves AS2 to first box
i = 1 => AS3 => deletes
```

---

You need to modify the list another way

- modify the current lists

  ```
  values = [['4H', '5D', '7C', 'AC'], ['AS', 'AS', 'AS']]
  for sublist in values:
      tmp_vals = list(sublist)
      sublist.clear()
      sublist.extend(elt for elt in tmp_vals if elt[0] != 'A')
  ```
- create new ones

  ```
  values = [['4H', '5D', '7C', 'AC'], ['AS', 'AS', 'AS']]
  values = [[elt for elt in sublist if elt[0] != 'A'] for sublist in values]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to remove the elements that start with `'A'`. If that is indeed the case and assuming that the nesting will be as the question suggests, you can do it in a single line:

```
lst = [list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('A'), sub)) for sub in lst]
```

which results in:

```
[['4H', '5D', '7C'], []]
```

Your approach is not working as intended because you are removing elements from the list while iterating through it, which is never a good idea. The approach above does not modify the list but rather re-creates it while keeping only the elements we want to have.

Also note that you should try to avoid using names that are Python built-ins such as `list` because you are overwriting them.

If you insist on modifying the list in-place, and re-thinking your beliefs is out of the question, iterate through your list in reverse:

```
lst = [['4H', '5D', '7C', 'AC'], ['AC', 'AS', 'AS']]
for sublist in lst[::-1]:
    for item in sublist[::-1]:
        if item[0] == 'A':
            sublist.remove(item)
print(lst)  # -> [['4H', '5D', '7C'], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things, never call your lists `list` strings `str` dictionaries `dict` etc. Second thing is, never mutate a list you are iterating over.
Considering this, below uses list comprehension which creates a new list so you don't have to worry about iterating and mutating.

```
lst = [['4H', '5D', '7C', 'AC'], ['AC', 'AS', 'AS']]
newlst = [[string for string in l if string[0]!='A'] for l in last ]
```

output

```
[['4H', '5D', '7C'], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other people have suggested good solutions, but I don't think they are easy-to-understand for beginner, I have modified your code a little bit:

```
list = [['4H', '5D', '7C', 'AC'], ['AC', 'AS', 'AS']]
for i in list:
    for j in i[::1]:   # here I am making a copy i, so that removal from original i won't affect iteration
        if j[0] == 'A':
            i.remove(j)
```

Comment: This might be a personal thing, but I find this even harder to understand. If one insists in modifying in-place for whatever reason, I would suggest iterating through the lists from the back to the front.

Comment: i modified the OP's code thinking that it would be helpful for him/her. I thought it would be harder for him/her to understand list comprehension etc.